# How to refer to another window object in Pyqt6?

Tags: python, qt-designer, pyside6, pyqt6

Infinite recursion of initializer calls
File "E:\Work\PythonProjects\MyApp\Ui\main.py", line 14, in **init**
self.fp = FilterWindow()
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "E:\Work\PythonProjects\MyApp\Ui\main.py", line 454, in **init**
self.mn = MainWindow()
^^^^^^^^^^^^

SystemError: D:_w\1\s\Objects\longobject.c:1208: bad argument to internal function

```
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QWidget
from main_window import Ui_MainWindow
from filter_page import Ui_FilterForm
import sys

class MainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        self.fw = FilterWindow()
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        #  then the objects are created
        self.filter_page_enabled = 1
        #  connected
        self.button_open_filter_page.clicked.connect(self.open_filter_page)

    def open_filter_page(self):
        self.hide()
        self.fw.show()


class FilterWindow(QWidget, Ui_FilterForm):
    def __init__(self):
        self.mw = MainWindow()
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        # connected
        self.button_close_filter_page.clicked.connect(self.change_filter_page_enabled)

    def change_filter_page_enabled(self):
        self.mw.filter_page_enabled = 0
        self.close()
        self.mw.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
   app = QApplication(sys.argv)
   window = MainWindow()
   window.show()
   app.exec()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are overcomplicating things. you initialize `MainWindow` a second time in `FilterWindow`; but, `FilterWindow` needs to be working with the same instance of `MainWindow` you've already initialized. You can initialize `FilterWindow` in `MainWindow`, passing the current instance of `MainWindow` ('self') to `FilterWindow` (i.e. `FilterWindow(self)`). You should do the same with the main window UI (i.e. `self.main_window = Ui_MainWindow(self)`). I assumed the following for this example.

> `FilterWindow(QWidget)`
> `Ui_MainWindow(QGroupBox)`
> `Ui_FilterForm(QFormLayout)`

Now, you set `self.parent = main_window` in both allowing you to connect MainWindow's `manage_filter_page` function to a button within `Ui_MainWindow`.

main.py

```
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QMainWindow, QPushButton
from main_window import Ui_MainWindow
from filter_page import Ui_FilterForm
import sys


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.main_window = Ui_MainWindow(self)
        self.main_window.setupUi()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.main_window)
        self.fw = FilterWindow(self)

    def manage_filter_page(self):
        if self.fw.isHidden():
            self.fw.show()
        else:
            assert not self.fw.isHidden()
            self.fw.hide()


class FilterWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, main_window):
        super().__init__()
        self.parent = main_window
        self.filter_form = Ui_FilterForm(self)
        self.filter_form.setupUi()
        self.setLayout(self.filter_form)


if __name__ == '__main__':
   app = QApplication(sys.argv)
   window = MainWindow()
   window.show()
   app.exec()
```

main_window.py

```
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QGroupBox, QVBoxLayout, QLabel, QPushButton


class Ui_MainWindow(QGroupBox):
    def __init__(self, main_window):
        super().__init__()
        self.parent = main_window

    def setupUi(self):
        vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        self.button = QPushButton("FILTER PAGE", self)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.parent.manage_filter_page)
        vbox.addWidget(self.button)
        vbox.addWidget(QLabel("MAIN WINDOW"))
        vbox.addWidget(QLabel("OTHER WORDS"))
        vbox.addWidget(QLabel("CONTENT HERE"))
        self.setLayout(vbox)
```

filter_page.py

```
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QLineEdit, QGroupBox, QFormLayout, QLabel


class Ui_FilterForm(QFormLayout):
    def __init__(self, filter_window):
        super().__init__()
        self.parent = filter_window
        self.name = QLineEdit()
        self.date = QLineEdit()

    def setupUi(self):
        self.addRow(QLabel("NAME"), self.name)
        self.addRow(QLabel("DATE"), self.date)
```

When the button is clicked, it shows the filter page if it is hidden or hides the filter page if it is showing. I think this is what you were trying to do? This example would look like this:

[image]

- in this bare-bones example, passing the parent was only necessary for Ui_MainWindow to connect the button. But, I included it in the others as you would probably end up needing to do so anyways.